Can Dolly Mirror cause a relic's ability to trigger twice in Slay the Spire?
In Slay the Spire: The Board Game, die relics are used when you roll a specific number. The description for Dolly's Mirror states

When you roll a 1, trigger a die relic ability. It's owner gains the effect.

What happens if I use Dolly's Mirror on a die relic that also goes off when you roll a 1 like Necronomicon or Tungsten Rod? Will that relic's ability get triggered twice in one turn?
